# same code working in command line but not for others

Tags: python-2.7

when i execute like this

```
>>> import mysql.connector
```

its working 
but when i do the same using writing  import mysql.connector in test.py  and

```
>>> python test.py
```

then its throwing error like this

```
 python test.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
import mysql.connector
 File "mysql.py", line 5, in <module
```

> ImportError: No module named connector

PLease help.
My python version 2.7.15

Comment: Wow you're on Python 5! How did you time travel to get that version? That's the part I'm interested in. Okay: enough snark. I think you mean that your `mysql` package is version 5.7.10

Comment: You are probably using the "wrong" `python` when executing `python test.py` from your cmdline. Do `which python`, and adjust your PATH as necessary

Comment: sorry man it was typing mistake

Comment: "adjust your PATH as necessary" could you help please in mac

Comment: Do you have a file called "mysql.py" in the local directory that you're running the script in?

Comment: No currently not but i had it and deleted. But still i am getting this error.  my.py is the File name

Comment: you're *sure* you don't have that mysql.py file anywhere on your PYTHONPATH? It looks like that might be the issue. What's the output of `python -m site`? (put it in the question, along with output of `which python`)

Comment: My python version 2.7.15

Comment: >>>> python -m Dropbox/python/study/my.py   then output:
/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7: Import by filename is not supported.

Comment: @MattMessersmith thank you . Your comment helps me . Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
import mysql.connector
 File "mysql.py", line 5, in <module
```

implying that you have a *local* version of the `mysql` module, which is being loaded instead of the one in your site-packages. Simply delete `mysql.py` from your working directory (or anywhere it might be on your PYTHONPATH), and then the import should work.

HTH.